# Extend from class with overwritten Documentation

Tags: modelica, dymola

In Modelica/Dymola you can inherit from another class by using `extend`:

```
extends Modelica.Magnetic.FluxTubes.BaseClasses.Force(dlBydx=-1);
```

This will extend from the `Force` class but overwrites the default parameter `dlBydx` with `-1`.

Now the question: most classes also contain a documentation and an icon (that is e.g. used in Dymola's graphics view). Is it possible to extend from a class but ignore the documentation section including the icon so it can be overwritten in the new class?

I try to give a reduced (and thus non-sense) but complete example...

```
model Force "Base class"

  parameter Integer dlBydx=1;

equation 
  F_m = dlBydx * 0.5;

  annotation (Icon(coordinateSystem(
      preserveAspectRatio=false,
      extent={{-100,-100},{100,100}}), graphics={
      Rectangle(
        extent={{30,30},{70,-30}},
        lineColor={255,128,0},
        fillColor={255,255,255},
        fillPattern=FillPattern.Solid),
      Line(points={{-70,0},{-90,0}}, color={255,128,0})}), Documentation(info="<html>
<p>
This is the documentation of the base class.
</p>
</html>"));
end Force;


model Force_New "Derivated class"
  extends Force(Icon()); //here I want to extend from Force with an empty icon in the new model but this line gives an error of course!
end Force_New;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you would like to extend a base-class without the icon and documentation:

1. The icon can be ignored/removed by adding `annotation (IconMap(primitivesVisible=false))`. For you this would result in:

   ```
   model Force_New "Derivated class without icon"
     extends Force annotation(IconMap(primitivesVisible=false));
   end Force_New;
   ```
2. The documentation is not extended by default. So you shouldn't have to do anything here.

Comment: Great stuff, thank you very much - this makes my model so much easier to read.
However, the documentation is extended unfortunately. Your solution hides to original icon - great - but the docu is still there :(

Comment: So for me, Dymola does not extend the documentation - also not with your example from above. Are you using Dymola or any other tool?

Comment: Ups, you are right. Sorry. There must have been something wrong with my test. I can second that now. The only thing coming from the extended model is the parameters section in the docu, which completely makes sense.